# Is there a good, cheap way of making isometric maps or similar for RPG campaigns?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, map-making

I want to make a digital isometric world map for my campaign world, both for my own planning purposes and to share with the players as they explore my upcoming homebrew Pathfinder campaign.

Preferably this should be:

- digital
- tile based with symbols you can put on each one
- easily share-able

Or alternatively tell me why I am wrong to want these things and suggest other ways of making good campaign maps for both players and GMs. I've seen software for something like $80 dollars, but that is way out of my price range.

Comment: @GenericShampoo As the question is currently posed, it seems like a Shopping question, [which is off-topic in general SE](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). [You could simply state your problem and wait for proposed solutions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5787/43856), instead of stating the problem and stating the solution you want.

Comment: It should be on-topic in Software Recommendations on StackExchange.